# Trouble accessing HTML form data using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a file upload form and I'm having trouble with the very basics.  My form is this:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action="fileuploader.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="filename" />
         <input type="submit"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

My php code so far is one line and it doesn't do anything:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['filename'];
?>
```

The idea (at this point) is just to display the name of the file entered in the form.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can print the filename using the following code:

```
<?php
echo $_FILES["filename"]["name"];
?>
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work. But then I added it to the same file as the form and it works that way.  Shouldn't it work with the PHP in a separate file?

Comment: Correction - That DID work.  But why didn't $_POST work?  I thought you were supposed to be able to access form values with it.

Comment: You use $_FILES because it is not a common field such as the ones you pass informations in text. It's special cos you are working with a different kind of data. I'd recommend reading what PHP docs says about it :: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code I modified it. Have a try it.

**HTML Part**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="fileuploader.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="filename" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // Check if files array is not empty
  if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $imageName = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    echo $imageName;
    // Insert your code related to upload 
  }
}
```